# Debugging incomplete type errors with thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I've had a bunch of thrust debugging to do with unary_function and binary_functions but and I've managed to hunt them don. All but one and incomplete type error in yes_type in:

```
namespace is_assignable_ns
{

template<typename T1, typename T2>
  class is_assignable
{
  typedef char                      yes_type;
  typedef struct { char array[2]; } no_type;

  template<typename T> static typename add_reference<T>::type declval();

  template<unsigned int> struct helper { typedef void * type; };

  template<typename U1, typename U2> static yes_type test(typename helper<sizeof(declval<U1>() = declval<U2>())>::type);

  template<typename,typename> static no_type test(...);

  public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T1,T2>(0)) == 1;
}; // end is_assignable

} // end is_assignable_ns
```

would anyone know which thrust operations this would likely to get called from the ones that I'm currently using:

```
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
```

The only error I have to work with is:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\include\thrust/detail/type_traits.h(607): error : incomplete type is not allowed
```

Any way to debug this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in a thrust::unique() turns out the structs that I was using in unique operator= wasn't returning and hence returned a incomplete type when passed through yes_type().

Comment: And how could anyone possibly have known that based in what you posted in your question?

Comment: Sorry I should have set up the question better I was more asking for techniques for debugging than to solve my problem directly. I was under no illusion that it wouldn't be possible given the information as the alternative would have been hundreds of lines of code. I was more hoping that someone who knew the library would know which thrust section used a yes_type